# How do I get to know value of this unusual character? square matrix having digits inside

Tags: c, sockets, character-encoding, special-characters

[image]

The uploaded image shows unusual characters **(square matrix having digits written inside).** This is happening when I try to write

```
 write(fd, buf,len)'s `buf` variable using fprintf function.
```

Is there any way to interpret these characters ?

Additional info:- `write()` is having a socket fd to write on.
Please tell me , If I am missing anything here.
Also, please retag this post , because I don't know which tag is suitable for this post.
[edit] : please zoom the web page (using ctrl++), if these characters are not clearly visible.

Comment: What's the encoding of your console ? What the encoding of your runtime strings ?

Comment: @BenjaminToueg
$ echo $LC_CTYPE
                       (blank)
$ echo $LANG
en_IN
how do I find runtime encoding of strings ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are all [unprintable control characters](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C0_and_C1_control_codes), the box is just a way to print them. Another option is to not show them at all but then you wouldn't know about them as easily.

There's

- `0x1F` Unit separator
- `0x7F` Delete
- `0x01` Start of Heading
- `0x1C` File Separator

(You can read all of the above from the boxes already)

Since these are almost never used in text, you should probably not treat them as text. If you look at the meaning of them as control characters, they don't make sense even as control characters.

Answer (score 1):

Open the file in a hex editor.
Hex editors normally show the value of each character in both binary and hexadecimal values.

Comment: I found the value of these characters , now ,I want to know if they are used as control characters over the network (socket programming)?

Comment: @AkshayPatil, that’s a completely different question and should be asked as a new question, but it would need to be much more specific – the use of control characters very much depends on protocols and programs.

Answer (score 1):

Clearly, those are "non printable" characters (in your current language, but quite possibly in all languages). Use `fprintf("%02x, %02x, %02x, %02x", buf[0], buf[1], buf[2], buf[3]);` to show their actual value.